# Unable to access postgres in docker from web app in another container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a samle app I'm using docker-compose to run locally on my machine. The web app is in one container and the db (postgres) in another.

I am having an connection issue that I can't work through.

docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'


services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'password'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      APP_FRONTEND_PORT: '8080'
      DB_PORT: '5433'
      DB_HOST: 'db'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      - 'db'

volumes:
    postgres-db:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest
WORKDIR /scratch
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build  -o /bin/frontend ./...

FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /go/bin/
COPY --from=build /bin/frontend /go/bin/frontend
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/frontend"]
```

Both containers are running and I'm able to log into the running postgres container and postgres  us running.

When I try to run a update from the US I get a 500 error and it does not seem like the app container can communicate with the db container. I'm not sure what I'm missing

client side error when trying to make a call to update date:

```
encountered err: failed to begin transaction: failed to connect to `host=db user=postgres database=postgres`: dial error (dial tcp 172.29.0.2:5433: connect: connection refused)
```

`docker ps` yeilds:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
19eeed869434   sample_app   "/go/bin/frontend"       48 minutes ago   Up 48 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   sample_app_1
84804f00c751   postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   48 minutes ago   Up 48 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   sample_app_db_1
$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per stated in https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/, you need to put both services into a user-defined bridge network for them to refer to each other by the container names. Here is how to do it inside `docker-compose.yml`:

1. Define a custom bridge network:

```
networks:
  some-name:
    driver: bridge
```

2. Put both services into that network:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'password'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - some-name
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    environment:
      APP_FRONTEND_PORT: '8080'
      DB_PORT: '5433'
      DB_HOST: 'db'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      - 'db'
    networks:
      - some-name
```

3. Force specific container names especially the one being referred to by the other, otherwise docker-compose will add prefix and suffix to the service name as the container name like `sample_app_db_1`:

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'password'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - some-name
```

Comment: I was looking at different docs https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ (this seems to be more inline with the version of the compose API (3.8) that I was using. 

When I tested using the user-defined bridge method I get invalid option.


```  
Unsupported config option for services.app: 'network'
Unsupported config option for services.db: 'network'
```

Comment: @JerryJonesII, fixed wrong syntax in the sample. Sorry about that.

Comment: While the bridge does seem to be getting defined I'm still getting the 500 error when trying to communicate with the db when doing the update method in the app. When I check the logs on the container its pretty much the same:
TODO-APP | 2021/05/27 09:58:01 error:  failed to begin transaction: failed to connect to `host=db user=postgres database=postgres`: dial error (dial tcp 172.31.0.2:5433: connect: connection refused)

Comment: @JerryJonesII What if I say you got the port number wrong? 5432 or 5433?